# My Centos Server DNS resolves to 127.0.0.1 and not the real IP

Tags: dns-server

Im using CWP on CentOS 7, it was working just fine but some time from now, my DNS Server resolves all my domains to 127.0.0.1. So I could open up a page that were hosted on my vps on my clients ether phone or pc and it directly tried to open up localhost.

Then I used dnschecker.org [DnsChecker showing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LxIY.png) to see what was going on and on some geographic locations were pointing correctly to the IP from my VPS and to others to the localhost (127.0.0.1).

I think it might be some kinda malware installed on my server because this is not normal.

Comment: To debug a DNS, you use `dig @server-name-or-ip <domain-name>`. Have you tried that? What is the output? (please copy paste in your question)

Answer (score 0):

I registered a free domain for testing purposes and this is the result I get from dig command:

; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-26.P2.el7_9.8 <<>> @vps.compu-mecanic.com compu-test.tk
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 44567
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 3
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;compu-test.tk.                 IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
compu-test.tk.          14400   IN      A       104.225.217.18

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
compu-test.tk.          86400   IN      NS      ns4.compu-mecanic.com.
compu-test.tk.          86400   IN      NS      ns3.compu-mecanic.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns3.compu-mecanic.com.  14400   IN      A       104.225.217.18
ns4.compu-mecanic.com.  14400   IN      A       185.136.96.99

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 104.225.217.18#53(104.225.217.18)
;; WHEN: Sat Jan 15 15:47:10 MST 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 143

---

And this is what I get from pinging this domain from my computer
Pinging compu-test.tk [127.0.0.1] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms